# Working with carbon as a material

Tags: material-science

I'm interested in building a robot with a carbon shell, and was wondering where I could find some ressources about how to work with carbon. For example, where to find it, how to shape it, and how to work with it.

Thank you

Comment: Graphite carbon is not very solid, it makes a mess, and  diamond is hard and expensive. Why would you want a carbon shell? It's a strange question. You could make something using hard coals, but what's wrong with metal or plastic?

Comment: I figured it was light and resistant, and I also like how it looks like. Metal is heavy and plastic isn't resistant.

Comment: Hmm, this is more of an engineering question, and thus off topic. Please read the [faq] before posting a question here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting mixed up with "carbon fibre"? This is a composite material made from epoxy resin strengthened with carbon fibres and it's widely used where very strong but light materials are needed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-fiber-reinforced_polymer for details.

If it is carbon fibre you're interested in then just Google for "carbon fibre" or something similar. I've just tried this and immediately found http://www.carbonmods.co.uk/Departments/carbon-fiber-kits.aspx, which looks the sort of thing that would be suitable for you.